# loading custom code onto SparkFun Blynk Board

Tags: wifi, servo

we're trying to add some code to the SparkFun Blynk Board. We don't want to overwrite the firmware, because that allows it to work with the iphone app, but we need to add our own voids and Blynk. Write commands in order to control this servo RC car via wifi wit the Joystick XY. any ideas?

our code:

```
#include <Servo.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <BlynkSimpleEsp8266.h>
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
//#define BLYNK_PRINT Serial

char BlynkAuth[] = "6dfb81c116d84003a505056239c23559";
char ssid[] = "Linksys23266";
char pass[] = "roboboyz";

Servo servoR;
Servo servoL;

int pos = 90;


void forward()
{
  servoR.write(110);
  servoL.write(110);
}

void turnRight()
{
  servoR.write(80);
  servoL.write(90);
  delay (2000);
}

void turnLeft()
{
  servoR.write(90);
  servoL.write(80);
  delay(2000);
}

void reverse()
{
  servoR.write(70);
  servoL.write(70);
  delay(2000);
}

void Stop()
{
  servoR.write(94);
  servoL.write(94);
  delay(2000);
}

void setup()
{
  Blynk.begin(BlynkAuth, ssid, pass);  // wifi username and password
  servoR.attach(12);
  servoL.attach(13);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(1000);
}

BLYNK_WRITE(V1) 
{
  int x = param[0].asInt();
  int y = param[1].asInt();

  // Do something with x and y
  Serial.print("X = ");
  Serial.print(x);
  Serial.print("; Y = ");
  Serial.println(y);
  if(y>220)
  forward();
  else if(y<35)
  reverse();
  else if(x>220)
  turnRight();
  else if(x<35)
  turnLeft();
  else
  Stop();
}

void loop()
{
  Blynk.run();
}
```

Comment: Is this something I'd have to send serial from the Blynk Board of the Joystick X/Y over wifi to another microcontroller, like a Leonardo? How would I do that? Can you add "serial.write" into the blynk board to get that information?

Comment: do you really want your steering to travel thousands of miles instead of dozens of feet?

Comment: Functions aren't called voids. They are called functions.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how microcontrollers work. You have one firmware and only one firmware. When you upload firmware you replace the existing firmware. You cannot "add" to it.

Instead you will have to write a new firmware that contains *all* the code you need to do the *entire* job.

Comment: Technically all bootloaders prove this wrong.

Comment: @Ghanima Yeah, all right Mr Pedant. Bootloaders are a completely separate program stored in a separate section of memory and run separately to your main firmware. You don't modify them either.

Comment: A bootloader does not modify existing code. A bootloader deletes existing code and replaces it with completely different code. Just because the bootloader happens to live in flash alongside your program and you have the option of running that instead of your program and it happens to accept programming data and write that to flash it does not "prove it all wrong" since the bootloader does precisely what I described in my answer.

Comment: Well, the blynk board is pretty damn limited then, as I can upload a whole crapton of custom code to virtually any other microcontroller. 

we're going to try and send ints from the XY coming in via wifi to the Blynk board via serial to another controller.

Comment: @Nick You can upload all the code you like, you just have to make sure that it includes the code you require to communicate with the iPhone app.

Comment: @Majenko what about with the custom Voids I have? will that mess anything up at all? we're just trying to have the XY values pass through those voids so they can drive the car (aka sending PWM values to the servo motors).

Comment: I don't know, I have never used Blynk. Maybe you should check out the Blynk Arduino library. It's linked from the getting started page. I am sure it has examples you can build on.

Comment: A bootloader resides in code memory and runs on the µc hence it is firmware. It furthermore allows to store and run other pieces of software - that also qualifies as firmware. So there are two pieces of firmware on the system and that contradicts the point your answer makes *one and only one*... I know that it is beyond doubt that you know how firmware and bootloaders work and I also know that this is mainly beside the point of the question. So, my apologies if you considered my comment inapt.

Comment: @Ghanima A bootloader does not and can not modify existing firmware. So what if it sits there in flash? So what if it allows you to replace code wholesale. It still **cannot modify existing firmware!**

Comment: @Ghanima Oh, and the keyword you have conveniently completely ignored there is "***YOU***". The user only has one firmware. The bootloader is not something the user ever should tinker with. The user can only upload (yes, using the bootloader if there is one) ***ONE*** piece of firmware, and only ***ONE*** piece of firmware runs at a time and that firmware ***CANNOT*** be modified.